# Show push notification on specific dates

Tags: android, push-notification

When creating the android application, I encountered the problem of showing push notifications on certain dates, when the application is closed.
The text of notification depends on date whet it has to be shown.
e.g.

```
if date = date1, show notificationText 1
if date = date2, show notificationText 2
...
if date = dateN, show notificationText N
```

I`m stuck and got no idea, how to realize this.
Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: had you tried something?

Comment: once you received the notification, register it through alaram manager

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16889775/603270